# What are the coordinates of the Schiaparelli parachute?

Tags: mars, schiaparelli-lander

Schiaparelli crashed at 2.05°S 6.21°W. It's parachute was jettisoned and landed a bit further off. What are the coordinates of the landing site of the parachute?

Answer (score 5):

MRO's [photo](https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/8131/signs-of-schiaparelli-test-lander-seen-from-orbit/) found something, likely the parachute, about 900 m south and 150 m east of the lander.
[image]

This is verified in an [archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20161028021912/http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/ExoMars/Detailed_images_of_Schiaparelli_and_its_descent_hardware_on_Mars) of an ESA report "Detailed images of Schiaparelli and its descent hardware on Mars."
[image: ESA's photo]

Comment: I think you are saying that the separation is so small that the latitude and longitude are practically the same. (The latitude may be 2.07 S or 2.08 S.)

Comment: Yes.  Where things ended up, it's more useful to say where the parachute is relative to the lander (and where all the debris are relative to each other).  It would have been more useful to say where the parachute is relative to the planet's parallels and meridians, had it ended up much farther away.